# About group actions, is there another notation to represent the set $X^G$?

Tags: group-theory, notation, group-actions

Let $G$ a group acting on $X$. This is the set of all fixed points of $X$:
$$
X^G = \{x\in X : g(x) = x, \forall g\in G\}
$$

Let $T\subseteq X$ and $x\in X$. We know that, this one is the stabilizer, the fixed set, and the orbit:
$$
G_x = Stab_G(x) = \{g\in G : g(x) = x\} \\
G_T = Fix_G(T) = \{g\in G : g(x) = x, \forall x\in T\} \\
G.x = G(x) = Orb_G(x) = \{g.x = g(x) : g\in G\}
$$

Apparently [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Fixed_points_and_stabilizer_subgroups) prefers the notation of $X^G$ and $G_X$ and $G_T$ and $G_x$ and $G.x$ and etc. Call it, notation $01$. But some [other sources](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_Theorem) prefers $Stab_G(x)$ or $Fix_G(T)$ or $Orb_G(x)$, call it, notation $02$.

**Question:** Is there a notation $02$ for $X^G$? Say.. something like $FixedPoint_X(G)$? If there is, I couldn't find it anywhere...

Comment: I usually see $X^G$ instead of $X_G$.

Comment: @E.Joseph Oh! Apparently you are right. Wiki uses $X^g$. Well.. But I also saw $X_G$ somewhere....

Comment: In a context where $X^G$ can be mistaken with the set of functions from $G$ to $X$, maybe it is preferable to use $X_G$ instead. But I think otherwise that $X^G$ is a pretty standard notation.

Comment: If you truly can't find anything suitable, and you find you really do need alternative notation, you can always make something up.

Comment: $X_G$ can be used to mean the set of $G$-orbits.